# Best approach to write huge xml data to file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xmlwriter

I'm currently exporting a database table with huge data *(100000+ records)* into an xml file using *XmlTextWriter class* and I'm writing directly to a file on the physical drive.

```
_XmlTextWriterObject = new XmlTextWriter(_xmlFilePath, null);
```

While my code runs ok, my question is that is it the best approach? Should I instead write the whole xml in memory stream first and then write the xml document in physical file from memory stream? And what are the effects on memory/ performance in both cases?

**EDIT**

Sorry that I could not actually convey what I meant to say.Thanks Ash for pointing out.
I will indeed be using XmlTextWriter but I meant to say whether to pass a physical file path string to the XmlTextWriter constructor (or, as John suggested, to the `XmlTextWriter.Create()` method) or use stream based api. My current code looks like the following:

```
XmlWriter objXmlWriter = XmlTextWriter.Create(new BufferedStream(new FileStream(@"C:\test.xml", FileMode.Create, System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights.Write, FileShare.None, 1024, FileOptions.SequentialScan)), new XmlWriterSettings { Encoding = Encoding.Unicode, Indent = true, CloseOutput = true });
using (objXmlWriter)
{
   //writing xml contents here
}
```

Comment: @Filip, Take it easy!  Kayes has been a member for only 14 days and has asked just 5 questions.

Comment: When dealing with any type of large file I would avoid loading it all into memory.  Instead use a stream based API to ensure only chunks of the file are in memory at any one time.  I believe XmlTextWriter let's you write element by element to a file.

Comment: @Filip
I'll try to be a good citizen @StackOverflow :) Happy now?

@Ash
Thanks. I actually intended to say wheather to use a stream based api. See the edit.

Comment: You don't need the BufferedStream anymore, that's inbuilt into the FileStream since 2

Comment: @Ash, @Kayes, it was not meant in any dissrespectfull way at all. More like a; Common you can do it! Or something like that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### While my code runs ok, my question is that is it the best approach?

As mentioned and your update, `XmlWriter.Create` is fine.

#### Or should I write the whole xml in memory stream first and then write the xml document in physical file from memory stream?

Do you have the memory to write the entire file in-memory? If you do then that approach will be faster, otherwise stream it using a `FileStream` which will take care of it for you.

#### And what are the effects on memory/ performance in both cases?

Reading the entire XML file in will use more memory, and spike the processor to start with. Streaming to disk will use more processor. But you'll need to be using a huge file for this to be noticeable given even desktop hardware now. If you're worried about the size increasing even more in the future, stick to the `FileStream` technique to future proof it.

Answer (score 9):

The rule of thumb is to use `XmlWriter` when the document need only be written and not worked with in memory, and to use `XmlDocument` (or the DOM) where you do need to work with it in memory.

Remember though, `XmlWriter` implements `IDisposable`, so do the following:

```
using (XmlWriter _XmlTextWriterObject = XmlWriter.Create(_xmlFilePath))
{
   // Code to do the write here
}
```

Comment: Actually, the rule is to use `XmlWriter.Create()` instead of `new XmlTextWriter()`. `XmlTextWriter` has been deprecated since .NET 2.0.

Comment: @John - Nice, I didn't know that. Edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

As John Saunders mentioned it is better to use XmlWriter.Create(). That is the recommendation from the MSDN. The XmlWriter.Create() method can also take an XmlWriterSettings object. There you can customize your behavior quite a bit. If you don't need validation and character checking then you can turn it off and get a bit more speed. For example

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.CheckCharacters = false;
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("path", settings))
{
    //writing code
    writer.Flush();
}
```

Otherwise I think everything is okay.